Laravel sail context
How can i get the laravel conetxt for copy using dockerfile?
I did: sail artisan sail:publish and i customized the dokcerfile a littebit but i'm tryb¡ng to copy a script that i had on the project root directpry but i can't.
My dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:22.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=20
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION=15

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV SUPERVISOR_PHP_COMMAND="/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80"

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 dnsutils librsvg2-bin fswatch ffmpeg \
    && curl -sS 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c' | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg > /dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.3-cli php8.3-dev \
       php8.3-pgsql php8.3-sqlite3 php8.3-gd \
       php8.3-curl \
       php8.3-imap php8.3-mysql php8.3-mbstring \
       php8.3-xml php8.3-zip php8.3-bcmath php8.3-soap \
       php8.3-intl php8.3-readline \
       php8.3-ldap \
       php8.3-msgpack php8.3-igbinary php8.3-redis php8.3-swoole \
       php8.3-memcached php8.3-pcov php8.3-imagick php8.3-xdebug \
    && curl -sLS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_VERSION.x nodistro main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && npm install -g pnpm \
    && npm install -g bun \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.3

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

#CUSTOM INSTALLS - PHP dependencies for sqlsrv database
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y \
    nano\
    lsb-release\
    software-properties-common

RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php &&\
    apt-get install php8.3 php8.3-dev php8.3-xml -y --allow-unauthenticated \
    unixodbc-dev &&\
    pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv &&\
    printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.3/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini &&\
    printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.3/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini &&\
    phpenmod -v 8.3 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
RUN pwd > /tmp/context.txt \
    && cat /tmp/context.txt

COPY ../../../../../odbc17.sh .
RUN /bin/bash -c 'odbc17.sh'


EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]


and it fails to the copy always because it doesn't found the script which i have in my project root folder.
I tried the relative path from project/docker/8.3/dockerfile and also from vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3 but i can't copy it

How are you building this Dockerfile?  You can never COPY ../... anything from a parent directory of the build context (the directory argument to a docker build command or the directory in a Compose build: directive).

Yep ... here's your problem: and it fails to the copy always because it doesn't found the script which i have in my project root folder <<<=== if the odbc.sh file is in the root of your project folder then your COPY command is different than what you have right now

And there's no way to add copy that script from root of the project without copying it?
